# What is the origin of the word "égarer"?

Tags: étymologie, ancien-français

What is the origin of the word [*Égarer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9garer)? It is shown as being derived from ancient French *es + garer* ([Lexique de l'ancien français](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Lexique_de_l%E2%80%99ancien_fran%C3%A7ais/15)).

Now *es* in latin is *ex*, but how does joining it to *garer* (which is hide or park) produces *perdu* or lost?

Comment: *Garer* doesn't  mean "to hide", where did you get that?

Answer (score 4):

As you say *égarer* is formed with Latin prefix ex/es - meaning "out of", and *garer*. If you understand what *garer* means ("to put aside") then it's easy to follow how the two words are related.

*Garer* is to put something in its proper place and "égarer" is to misplace something.

*Garer* comes form an old Norse word *varask* meaning "to beware" (*être sur ses gardes*). In Old French (12th century) the form *guerrer* meant "to defend oneself".  In the 15th century *garer* meant "to harbour a boat" then (17th century) it took the meaning of "to pull a vehicle over" (stop a vehicle on the side of the road in order to let another vehicle go past), and it could be used for anything that one wanted to put out of the way in order to protect it, in the 19th century it took its present meaning, i.e. to park a vehicle.

*Égarer* in Old French was used as an adjective to describe a troubled mind and then (12th century) it started being used as "to lose one's way" and from there to "misplace something".